# how to calculate time interval between player move and AI move

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Hii,
I want to calculate time taken by the player for making his move. My player can pick his coin and make his move to a box(like in chess). If my player pick his coin early but make his move very lately, then how to calculate time between AI and player move

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to reset/abort the move action if it is not finished after a certain amount of time, say 5 secs or whatever is reasonable to your game.